# How to Convert an multidimentional array into json array using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is my input array (PHP) which I tried to change into the JSON object array, I tried some of the predefined functions but not able to do, I am new to this

```
[educationTitle] => Array
    (
        [0] => Graduate
        [1] => Graduate
        [2] => Post Graduation Diploma
    )

[degree] => Array
    (
        [0] => B.E
        [1] => B.E
        [2] => Post Graduate Diploma - Law [P.G.D.L.L]
    )

[branch] => Array
    (
        [0] => ECE
        [1] => ECE
        [2] => PGD - Business Law
    )

[startDate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1970-01
        [1] => 1970-01
        [2] => 2018-01
    )

[endDate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1970-01
        [1] => 1970-01
        [2] => 2021-06
    )

[universityName] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => sdsdfsdfsdf
    )

[universityCity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
    )

[courseDescription] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => asasdasdasdasdasd
    )
```

Below is my output JSON in which I tried to change the above given array, I tried some of the predefined functions but not able to do, I am new to this

```
    "educationDetails": [
    {
      "educationTitle": "Graduate",
      "degree": "B.E",
      "branch": "ECE",
      "startDate": "2015-09-08",
      "endDate": "2019-05-09",
      "courseDescription": "",
      "universityName": "Anna University",
      "universityCity": "Chennai"
    },
    {
      "educationTitle": "Graduate",
      "degree": "B.E",
      "branch": "ECE",
      "startDate": "2015-09-08",
      "endDate": "2019-05-09",
      "courseDescription": "",
      "universityName": "Anna University",
      "universityCity": "Chennai"
    },
    {
      "educationTitle": "Graduate",
      "degree": "B.E",
      "branch": "ECE",
      "startDate": "2015-09-08",
      "endDate": "2019-05-09",
      "courseDescription": "",
      "universityName": "Anna University",
      "universityCity": "Chennai"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Your output has values that do not occur in the input, like `"Anna University"`. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is available as `$data`, then proceed like this:

```
foreach($data["startDate"] as $i => $_) {
    $item = [];
    foreach($data as $key => $values) {
        $item[$key] = $values[$i];
    }
    $result[] = $item;
}
```

At the end, the variable `$result` will look like this:

```
[
  [
    'educationTitle' => 'Graduate',
    'degree' => 'B.E',
    'branch' => 'ECE',
    'startDate' => '2015-09-08',
    'endDate' => '2019-05-09',
    'universityName' => 'Anna University',
    'universityCity' => 'Chennai',
    'courseDescription' => 'Mathematics',
  ], [
    'educationTitle' => 'Graduate',
    'degree' => 'B.E',
    'branch' => 'ECE',
    'startDate' => '2015-09-08',
    'endDate' => '2019-05-09',
    'universityName' => 'Anna University',
    'universityCity' => 'Chennai',
    'courseDescription' => 'Physics',
  ], [
    'educationTitle' => 'Post Graduation Diploma',
    'degree' => 'Post Graduate Diploma - Law   "P.G.D.L.L"',
    'branch' => 'PGD - Business Law',
    'startDate' => '2018-01-01',
    'endDate' => '2021-06-30',
    'universityName' => 'Anna University',
    'universityCity' => 'Chennai',
    'courseDescription' => 'Politics',
  ],
]
```

For JSON format, just call `json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`, and you get:

```
[
    {
        "educationTitle": "Graduate",
        "degree": "B.E",
        "branch": "ECE",
        "startDate": "2015-09-08",
        "endDate": "2019-05-09",
        "universityName": "Anna University",
        "universityCity": "Chennai",
        "courseDescription": "Mathematics"
    },
    {
        "educationTitle": "Graduate",
        "degree": "B.E",
        "branch": "ECE",
        "startDate": "2015-09-08",
        "endDate": "2019-05-09",
        "universityName": "Anna University",
        "universityCity": "Chennai",
        "courseDescription": "Physics"
    },
    {
        "educationTitle": "Post Graduation Diploma",
        "degree": "Post Graduate Diploma - Law   \"P.G.D.L.L\"",
        "branch": "PGD - Business Law",
        "startDate": "2018-01-01",
        "endDate": "2021-06-30",
        "universityName": "Anna University",
        "universityCity": "Chennai",
        "courseDescription": "Politics"
    }
]
```

print_r($result);